# Handling dependency and time gap between tests in testng

Tags: testng

I have two test classes A and B. Now B depends on A for test Data, the web service I test in B starts reflecting A's result only after 5 mins.So I don't want to wait for 5 mins and want to run few tests which are not at all dependent on A or B in between, if they are done and still 5 mins are not over i am ready to wait, and after 5 mins only i go for B. Is there any good way we can implement this in testng?

Answer (score 0):

Parallel test execution is probably way to go.

If you are using Maven, you can configure this as parameter for maven-surefire-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
      <parallel>methods</parallel>
      <threadCount>10</threadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Not sure about Ivy or Gradle, but it has to be possible also.

Comment: But how does it solve the issue of waiting 5 mins. So, I use testng xml to run my tests , i can ask to execute tests in parallel. But it still doesnt ensure test B gets executed after 5 mins of A, unless i trigger b from A after waiting for 5 mins. Is that what you are suggesting ?

Comment: I though your problem was that all other tests are blocked during long B test execution.

Comment: Do you have any triggers in DB for that? Are you aware of that it is not good practise to have test dependent on each other and on DB configuration. Each integration test ideally prepares its data in `@BeforeClass` for testing. And tidy up DB in `@AfterClass`. When you break that dependency, your problem is gone.